# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "siguieron siendo muy costosos" y "siguieron quedando muy costosos"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Cuanto me preparaba el examen del DELE B2, me encontré el siguiente problema:

> A pesar de que se hicieron grandes esfuerzos para mejorar los bolígrafos, estos siguieron _______ muy costosos.
>
> (A) **siendo**
> (B) estando
> (C) quedando

La respuesta es (A). No entiendo por qué (C) es incorrecto aquí.

Además, en el mismo párrafo, hay otra cuestión:

> Años más tarde lo patentó en Argentina, donde por vez primera se
> financió el invento para ______ comercializado e industrializado.
>
> (A) **ser** 
> (B) estar

La respuesta es (A). ¿Es por qué "comercializado e industrializado" es un resultado?

Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

> estos siguieron _______ muy costosos.

No puede ser "quedando" porque "quedando" sería redundante: "seguir", al igual que "quedar", ya indica permanencia. Puede decirse "siguieron siendo muy costosos" o "siguieron muy costosos", o "quedaron todavía muy costosos".

> se financió el invento para ______ comercializado e industrializado.

Esto es voz pasiva: "El invento fue comercializado". La voz pasiva siempre se forma con "ser". El objetivo de la financiación era "comercializar el invento", así que se financió "para que lo comercializaran", o "para ser comercializado".

Comment: Quien me haya votado negativo podría haber tenido el detalle de explicar por qué.

Comment: Lo mismo le digo a quien me haya dado el segundo negativo, aunque tengo un sospechoso.